# ASP.NET MVC: How does a controller distingush between parameters in the URL and sent by POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I would like to better understand how a controler method knows when a parameter it recives should be retrived from the post data or the url.

Take the following example:

```
URL: /ModelController/Method/itemID 
// Where itemID is the id (int) of the item in the database
POST: objectOrArray: {JSON Object/Array}
```

The controller would look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InputResources(int? id, Object objectOrArray)
```

Now, somehow the method is smart enough to look for the first parameter, the `id`, in the site URL and the `Object` in the `HTTPPost`.

Whilst this works, I don't know why, and as a result I sometimes run into unpredictable and erratic behaviour. For example, I seem to have found (although I am not 100% sure) that removing the `?` from `int? id` makes the controller method inmediately assume it should look for the id in the `HTTPPost` and not the URL.

So I would like to clarify the following points:

What exactly is it that tells the method where to look for the data? (The `[HttpPost]` attribute preciding the method?)

Do naming conventions come into play? (for example removint the `?` or not using `id` as the variable name?)

Does the order in which the variables are placed have an inpact? (ie placing the `Object` before the `id`)

I know I can more or less figure out some of this stuff by trial and error, but I would like a qualified explanation rather than to continiue to work of assumption based on observation.

Thank you

Chopo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the default route from `Global.asax`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                            
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                     
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The first thing that MVC will try to do is map your method parameters to values in the POST. If it doesn't find a match, it will cascade through other possibilities, including the route values.

Here's the order the model binder uses:

> 1. Previously bound action parameters, when the action is a child action
> 2. Form fields (Request.Form)
> 3. The property values in the JSON Request body (Request.InputStream), but only when the request is an AJAX request
> 4. Route data (RouteData.Values)
> 5. Querystring parameters (Request.QueryString)
> 6. Posted files (Request.Files)

The reason you're seeing the behaviour you describe is because POST data comes before route values. It seems that MVC can't bind a nullable int to a POST value, so it skips over it and keeps going until it reaches the `RouteData` mapping, at which point, it finds a match and gets the value from the route. When you make the parameter non-nullable, it is suddenly able to bind it to the POST value, which has higher precedence than `RouteData`, so it does.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: Thank you, great answer. And also great source reference provided